# How to benchmark the methods inside JUnit test?

Tags: java, performance, maven, maven-3

I need to identify the slow running methods inside JUnit test class. For example Surefire site report can give me the test methods running time, but how to identify the running time of the methods inside?

I have the following contraption:

```
Programming language - Java
Build tool - Apache Maven
Test runner - Apache Surefire
Test driver- JUnit
Browser driver - Selenium WebDriver
Artifacts repository - Sonatype Nexus
Continious integration - Jenkins
SCM - Subversion (to be migrated to Git)
```

Comment: Why not defining an upper bound for execution time, measuring by yourself with currentTimeMillis and handling it with assert timeNeeded < upperBound?

Comment: I would rather prefer more automated solution as I have hundreds of tests written by different people. The test suites are now taking a lot of time and I need to identify the slow running methods to speed the things up.

Comment: If you're considering an extra lib, [this](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks-tutorial.html) might help you with. You declare within your test class that you want to benchmark the tests and does the hard work for you. It output into the console the average time to complete those tasks you declared.

Comment: Another option might be JProfiler (http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)